# Is there a method to view Application Insights logs besides Azure Portal?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I am unable to endure clicking so many times in Azure Portal to get to AppInsights log analytics. Saving the URL to the analytics blade and returning to it also frequently fails to load the page due to what appear to be some authentication token expiration issues.

How can I run my Kusto queries on my AppInsights instance without using Azure Portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are running a private preview of the ability to use the Azure Data Explorer tools such as [Kusto Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer) and [Kusto Web explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/web-query-data) to query Log analytics and Application Insights.

If you are interested to join, please send a mail to adxproxy alias (@microsoft.com).

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi. Power BI helps to analyze data and share insights. Continuous export is also an option. You can export app-insights data to blob storage and analyze data using stream analytics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry