# Application Insights Desktop Applicaion

Tags: azure, desktop-application, azure-application-insights

My company is moving to Azure Application Insights. The logging is fine, but having to go into the Azure web portal to write a query stinks. Are there any desktop application to use like SSMS to query with? I have googled for it. but "Application Insights Application" is a bit redundant and didn't yield great results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 03/30:**

Here are the detailed steps(assume you have already downloaded  the tool):

1.Open `Kusto Explorer`, in the "Connections" menu -> select "Add group", and follow the screenshot below to add a group:

[image]

2.Right click the group name -> select "Add connection", then follow the screenshot below to create connection to your application insights:

[image]

3.When the connection is ok, you can expand the group, and your application insights is there; you can then write your query code to query data:

[image]

The referenced doc: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/query-monitor-data#additional-syntax-examples) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto).

---

**Original answer:**

You can use the client tool [Kusto Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/kusto-explorer) to query Application Insights logs. And here is already a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637262/is-there-a-method-to-view-application-insights-logs-besides-azure-portal).

For any details about that, please send a mail to `adxproxy@microsoft.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.